# Each time I press submit I want input text box change text

Tags: php, forms, submit

So basically I have a simple form and I want to change the input boxes text different every time you press submit by using PHP. I know my code doesn't work but I don't understand how to solve this problem. Maybe the array is not the best way to do this?

```
<body>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['submit'])) exit();
        $msg= ['One', 'Two', 'Three', '']
    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Paina nappi">
    <input type="text" name="msg" value="<?php echo (isset($msg)) ? $viesti : ''; ?>">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: where have you defined `$viesti` variable?

Comment: Oops, it was supposed to be the $msg variable. Do I need to make a for loop to loop through my array on each submit or something? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $msgArray= array('One', 'Two', 'Three', '');
    // if $_SESSION['msgIndex'] is not set, we initialize it, or it will take 0 value every loading page
    if (!isset($_SESSION['msgIndex'])) { $_SESSION['msgIndex'] = 0;  }

    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        getMessage();
    }

    // We save msgIndex in a $_SESSION variable cause even if the user reload the page, we keep the value
    function getMessage() {
        if ($_SESSION['msgIndex'] >= 0) {
            $_SESSION['msgIndex'] += 1;
        } if ($_SESSION['msgIndex'] > 3) {
            $_SESSION['msgIndex'] = 0;
        }
    }
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Paina nappi">
    <input type="text" name="msg" value="<?= $msgArray[$_SESSION['msgIndex']] ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly, just as I wanted! Only problem I had was that I had to put `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the start of the document under all of the html,head and body tags because otherwise I got an error.

Comment: Yep, cause if you use $_SESSION, you have to start a session with session_start(); . So what you could do is to create a file where you put all your PHP code inside with session_start at the beginning, and include that file in all your HTML file :)